# Liferay search hits returns only one user

Tags: jsp, liferay

I am trying to implement search functionality from Liferay for a custom search portlet. The problem is that I am getting only one result, that is the default user liferay supplies (test), although I have other users as well. Below is the code snippet I am using to implement the search. I am using liferay 7.0.

```
<%
String keywords = ParamUtil.getString(request, "keywords");

SearchContext searchContext = SearchContextFactory
    .getInstance(request);

    searchContext.setKeywords(keywords);
    searchContext.setAttribute("paginationType", "more");
    searchContext.setStart(0);
    searchContext.setEnd(10);

    Indexer indexer = IndexerRegistryUtil.getIndexer(User.class);

    Hits hits = indexer.search(searchContext);

    List<User> entries = new ArrayList<User>();


    for (int i = 0; i < hits.getDocs().length; i++) {
            Document doc = hits.doc(i);
            System.out.println(hits.doc(i).getUID());
            long entryId = GetterUtil
            .getLong(doc.get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK));

            User entry = null;

            try {
                    entry = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(entryId);
            } catch (PortalException pe) {
                    //_log.error(pe.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (SystemException se) {
                    //_log.error(se.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            entries.add(entry);
    }

    List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0,1000000);

    Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (User userr : users) {
        userMap.put(Long.toString(userr.getUserId()), userr.getFullName());
}%>
```

As it obvious, I am trying to search for users. As I said before, I can only search for the test user (provided by liferay) and not for all users.
Any help would be great!

Comment: Run `Server Administration` scripts from Control Panel first.

Comment: Also, you are adding user object in `entries` list, while you are iterating it through `users`, which is a different list. Why?

Comment: Actualy I am iterating through entries when I return results. I forgot to add that part of code.

Comment: When I am running Server Administration, I am getting all the users.

Comment: It would appear there wasn't a problem with the code. Users have to be configured (assigned role to as such) in order to appear in the search results.

Comment: How did you add your users to the database? Through Liferay's UI? LDAP? SQL-INSERT? Liferay's API?